# Plotting charts with python class: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'generate_plot'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I tried to generate charts with the following python class but it throws back an AttributeError. Can someone please help me fix this?

```py
from typing import Dict, Any
import streamlit as stl
import pandas as pd

class Chart:
    def __init__(self, dataframe: pd.DataFrame, config_dict: Dict[str, Any]):
        self._dataframe = dataframe
        self._config_dict = config_dict

    @abstractmethod
    def generate_plot(self) -> stl.plotly_chart:
        NotImplementedError()


def OpenCloseChart(Chart):
    def generate_plot(self) -> stl.plotly_chart:
        openCloseChart_fig = self._dataframe.iplot(
            y=self._config_dict['y_data'],
            secondary_y=self._config_dict['secondary_y'],
            secondary_y_title=self._config_dict['secondary_y_title'],
            xTitle=self._config_dict['xTitle'],
            yTitle=self._config_dict['yTitle'],
            title=self._config_dict['title'],
            asFigure=self._config_dict['asFigure'])
        return stl.plotly_chart(openCloseChart_fig)
```

I call on the class in the function below but it throws back AttributeError

```py
def create_open_close_chart(ticker_df: pd.DataFrame, name: str,
                                    start_date: str,
                                    end_date: str) -> stl.plotly_chart:
            config_dict = {
                'y_data': ticker_df.Open,
                "secondary_y": 'Close Price ($)',
                'secondary_y_title': "Close Price ($)",
                "xTitle": "Date",
                "yTitle": "Open Price ($)",
                "title":
                f"Open and Close Price of {name} From {start_date} To {end_date}",
                "asFigure": True
            }
            open_close_chart_obj = OpenCloseChart(Chart(ticker_df, config_dict))
            return open_close_chart_obj.generate_plot()

        create_open_close_chart(df, company_name, df_actual_start_date, end_date)
```

Error:
[image]

I expect an output as the fig below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you were trying to create an object, not a function, and use `class OpenCloseChart(Chart):` instead of `def OpenCloseChart(Chart):`

Comment: Hi anzhel! Thanks for your reply, I tried it but it doesn't work, I mean it throws a new error which is; ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: actually it worked:) this new error is just regarding your dataframe, if you could share it, I'll try to help with that also

Comment: and everything for us to be able to reproduce the code