# My chart class throws ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to plot my charts using python class but I get `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`. It would be a pleasure if anyone can help me fix it.
My class is as follows;

```py
from abc import abstractmethod
from typing import Dict, Any
import streamlit as stl
import pandas as pd


class Chart:
    def __init__(self, dataframe: pd.DataFrame, config_dict: Dict[str, Any]):
        self._dataframe = dataframe
        self._config_dict = config_dict

    @abstractmethod
    def generate_plot(self) -> stl.plotly_chart:
        NotImplementedError()


class OpenCloseChart(Chart):
    def generate_plot(self) -> stl.plotly_chart:
        openCloseChart_fig = self._dataframe.iplot(
            y=self._config_dict['y_data'],
            secondary_y=self._config_dict['secondary_y'],
            secondary_y_title=self._config_dict['secondary_y_title'],
            xTitle=self._config_dict['xTitle'],
            yTitle=self._config_dict['yTitle'],
            title=self._config_dict['title'],
            asFigure=self._config_dict['asFigure'])
        return stl.plotly_chart(openCloseChart_fig)
```

So I called the class in the function bellow

```py
def create_open_close_chart(ticker_df: pd.DataFrame, name: str,
                                    start_date: str,
                                    end_date: str) -> stl.plotly_chart:
            config_dict = {
                'y_data': ticker_df.Open,
                "secondary_y": ticker_df.Close,
                'secondary_y_title': "Close Price ($)",
                "xTitle": "Date",
                "yTitle": "Open Price ($)",
                "title":
                f"Open and Close Price of {name} From {start_date} To {end_date}",
                "asFigure": True
            }

            open_close_chart_obj = OpenCloseChart(ticker_df, config_dict)
            return open_close_chart_obj.generate_plot()

create_open_close_chart(ticker_df=df, name=company_name, start_date=df_actual_start_date, end_date=end_date)
```

The error message;

[image]

Espected out;

[image]

Comment: which line does raise the error ?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned under the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72661934/plotting-charts-with-python-class-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attr/72664142?noredirect=1#comment128361321_72664142), you need to provide more information for us to be able to reproduce the code